# Перенос строки не читается из файла

Tags: php, файлы

Что я делаю не так?

```
<?php

    $admlist = 'content/test.txt';
    $admcont = file_get_contents($admlist);
    $textfile = file_get_contents('content/text.txt');
    $admstring = "$textfile";
    $admcontold = array("$admstring");
    $admcontnew = array("");
    $admphrase  = str_replace($admcontold, $admcontnew, $admcont);
    if(file_put_contents($admlist, $admphrase)) {
        echo "success page\n";
    }

?>
```

Если 6 строку сменить на `$admstring = "\ntest";`, то все работает. C переменной же нет.
Задача: прочитать из строки перенос строки+текст, а потом его заменить в файле test.txt. Интересует именно этот вариант, но не понимаю, что делаю не так.

Comment: Может быть имеется в виду  $admstring = $textfile; То есть без кавычек.

Comment: пробовал без кавычек , не работает тоже

Comment: тут дело в том что , если написать строку то все меняется , а если эта строка в файле , и вместо нее подставить переменную которая прочитала файл , ничего не работает , очень странно , это баг что ли или что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает с переменной:

```
$textfile = "test"; // то, что возвращает file_get_contents, - та же строка.
$admstring = "\n$textfile"; // пишется так.
$admcontold = array($admstring); // кавычки не нужны, это переменная.

print_r($admcontold);
```

http://ideone.com/PRXWeQ